# CUDA_SAFE_CALL: an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: cuda

I am trying to do simple matrix multiplication on CUDA. I know arrays can be flattened for passing it to the device. However I am using cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2d to do the multiplication. While executing the code below I get an error " illegal memory was encountered" when I try to copy the result onto the host. I highly appreciate any advice on where I am going wrong. Thanks!

weights-first matrix,dim:30x784

input- second matrix,dim:784x100

results_d - result on the device(GPU)

result - result copied on the host

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(ans) \
  { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line,
                      bool abort = true) {
  if (code != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CUDA_SAFE_CALL: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),
            file, line);
    if (abort) exit(code);
  }
}

__global__ void MatrixMulKernel(double *input, double *weights,
                                double *results_d, size_t in_pitch,
                                size_t w1_pitch, size_t result_pitch) {
  int row = threadIdx.x;
  int col = threadIdx.y;
  double value;
  double *result_matrix;

  result_matrix = ((double *)((char *)results_d + row * result_pitch + col));

  printf("%d", threadIdx);

  for (int i = 0; i < in_pitch; i++)

  {
    double *element1 = ((double *)((char *)input + row * in_pitch) + i);
    double *element2 = ((double *)((char *)weights + i * w1_pitch) + col);

    value = +(*element1) * (*element2);
  }

  *result_matrix = value;
}

int main() {
  static double arr1[30][784];
  static double arr2[784][100];
  static double result[30][100];

  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)

  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 784; j++) arr1[i][j] = 5;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 784; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) arr2[i][j] = 3;
  }

  double *input;
  double *weights;
  double *results_d;

  size_t in_pitch, w1_pitch, result_pitch;

  // allocating memory in GPU for 2 inputs and result
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(
      cudaMallocPitch((void **)&input, &in_pitch, 100 * sizeof(double), 784));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(
      cudaMallocPitch((void **)&weights, &w1_pitch, 784 * sizeof(double), 30));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMallocPitch((void **)&results_d, &result_pitch,
                                 100 * sizeof(double), 30));

  // Copy matrix from host to device
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(input, in_pitch, arr2, 100 * sizeof(double),
                              100 * sizeof(double), 784,
                              cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(weights, w1_pitch, arr1, 784 * sizeof(double),
                              784 * sizeof(double), 30,
                              cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(results_d, result_pitch, result,
                              100 * sizeof(double), 100 * sizeof(double), 30,
                              cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

  // using GPU

  dim3 dimGrid(1, 1, 1);
  dim3 dimBlock(32, 32, 1);
  printf("before kernel fucntion");
  MatrixMulKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(input, weights, results_d, in_pitch,
                                         w1_pitch, result_pitch);
  printf("after kernel fucntion");
  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  // copying back to host
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(result, result_pitch, results_d,
                              100 * sizeof(double), 100 * sizeof(double), 30,
                              cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  // printing and seeing whether the result matrix has been updated
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
      printf("%f", result);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(input));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(weights));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(results_d));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code. it is completely unreadable as posted

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c) for `cudaMallocPitch`.  The `pitch` value returned by that function is a value in **bytes**.  You cannot sensibly use that as a loop index for matrix multiplication.  Furthermore `pitch` gives the width of the entire allocation.  Your loop variable should only traverse the defined row/column length (i.e. 784 in this case) which you don't seem to be passing to your kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of errors in this code.  First of all, it's not clear that doing pitched allocations is going to give any benefit here.  Second, if you're serious about wanting fast matrix multiply performance, you should use CUBLAS.

Issues:

1. You don't seem to understand pitched allocations.  The `pitch` value returned is a value in **bytes**.  You cannot sensibly use that for a loop index for matrix multiply.  Also, the `pitch` value is the overall width of the pitch allocation.  It does not correspond to the valid data area.  For that, you should use the appropriate matrix dimension.
2. Your code will not do a matrix multiplication over the entire matrix area.  You are only creating a single block of 32x32 threads, but you need enough blocks/threads to cover the entire matrix area.  This requires changes to your grid dimensions, passing matrix dimensions to your kernel,  as well as a "thread check" in your kernel to prevent out-of-bounds access.
3. This construct for pitched access is not correct:

   ```
   result_matrix = ((double*)((char*)results_d + row*result_pitch + col));
   ```

   it does not match the other constructions you have for the 2 input matrices, it has a misplaced close parenthesis.
4. You have the sense of your two input matrices reversed.  You are indexing into the `input` matrix as if it were the `weight` matrix, and vice-versa.  We need to swap the sense of `row`, `column` and `i` to make these match the actual matrix dimensions.
5. Your final `cudaMemcpy2D` operation has the pitch values reversed:

`cudaMemcpy2D(result,result_pitch,results_d,100*sizeof(double),100*sizeof(double),30,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)`

```
                    ^^^^^                   ^^^^^
```

6. You forgot to initialize to zero your loop sum variable:

   ```
   double value;
   ```
7. I don't know what you intended here, it should be `+=` not `=+`:

   ```
   value =+ ...
   ```

The following code has these issues addressed, and seems to run without error for me:

```
$ cat t104.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

const int d1 = 30;
const int d2 = 784;
const int d3 = 100;

double arr1[d1][d2];
double arr2[d2][d3];
double result[d1][d3];


#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"CUDA_SAFE_CALL: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

__global__ void MatrixMulKernel(double *input,double *weights,double *results_d,size_t in_pitch,size_t w1_pitch,size_t result_pitch, int dim, int rrow, int rcol)
{
  int col = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int row=  threadIdx.y + blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;

  if ((row >= rrow) || (col >= rcol)) return;

  double value = 0;
  double *result_matrix;

  result_matrix = ((double*)((char*)results_d + row*result_pitch) + col);

  for(int i =0 ; i < dim ; i++)

  {

    double *element1 = ((double*)((char*)input + i*in_pitch) + col) ;
    double *element2 =   ((double*)((char*)weights + row*w1_pitch) + i);

    value += (*element1) * (*element2);

  }

  *result_matrix = value;

}





int main()
{


  for (int i = 0 ; i < d1; i++)

  {
    for(int j =0;j <d2 ; j ++)
      arr1[i][j] = 5;

  }

  for (int i =0 ; i < d2; i ++)
  {

    for(int j=0;j < d3 ; j++)
      arr2[i][j] = 3;

  }



  double *input;
  double *weights;
  double *results_d;

  size_t in_pitch,w1_pitch,result_pitch;



//allocating memory in GPU for 2 inputs and result
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMallocPitch((void**)&input,&in_pitch,d3*sizeof(double),d2));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMallocPitch((void**)&weights,&w1_pitch,d2*sizeof(double),d1));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMallocPitch((void**)&results_d,&result_pitch,d3*sizeof(double),d1));

//Copy matrix from host to device
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(input,in_pitch,arr2,d3*sizeof(double),d3*sizeof(double),d2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(weights,w1_pitch,arr1,d2*sizeof(double),d2*sizeof(double),d1,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(results_d,result_pitch,result,d3*sizeof(double),d3*sizeof(double),d1,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));


//using GPU


  dim3 dimBlock(32,32,1);
  dim3 dimGrid(((d3+dimBlock.x-1)/dimBlock.x),((d1+dimBlock.y-1)/dimBlock.y),1);
  MatrixMulKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(input, weights,results_d,in_pitch,w1_pitch,result_pitch, d2, d1, d3);

//copying back to host
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(result,d3*sizeof(double),results_d,result_pitch,d3*sizeof(double),d1,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


//printing and seeing whether the result matrix has been updated
  for (int i =0 ; i < d3; i ++)
  {

    for(int j=0;j < d1 ; j++)
    {
      printf("%f", result[j][i]);

    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(input));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(weights));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(results_d));


  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t104 t104.cu
$
```